# Complex audio volume changes with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Using `ffmpeg`, how much control can we have over the audio levels? For example, I would like to map an "M" shape over the program's timeline:

```
t0 - t1 : fade in from 0 to 1
t1 - t2 : play at full volume
t2 - t3 : fade out to 25%
t3 - t4 : play at 25% volume
t4 - t5 : fade in (from 25%) to full volume
t5 - t6 : play at full volume
t6 - t7 : fade out from 1 to 0
```

Can this be done? The combinations I've tried (of afade and volume, and using timeline editing) have not been successful so far.

Here is something that is close:

```
ina="infile.caf"
out="outfile.mp3"

time ffmpeg -i $ina -af \
"afade=enable='between(t,0,3)':t=in:ss=0:d=3, \
afade=enable='between(t,7,8)':t=out:st=7:d=1, \
volume=enable='between(t,8,12)':volume=.25:eval=frame, \
afade=enable='between(t,12,13)':t=in:st=12:d=1, \
afade=enable='between(t,15,18)':t=out:st=15:d=3" \
$out
```

.. but at the two middle points (the point where it fades out to 25%, and the point where it fades back in to full volume) there are glitches - audible sound clicks.

Comment: What command have you tried?

Comment: @Mulvya, I added an example of what I've been trying. Which is close, but not yet acceptable.

Comment: Fade filters go to or start from zero. You should do it entirely using volume filters. I'll supply an answer shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to suggest to do it entirely using volume filters, but it can be done the current way with minor modifications.

```
ffmpeg -i $ina -af \
"afade=enable='between(t,0,3)':t=in:ss=0:d=3, \
afade=enable='between(t,7,8)':t=out:st=7:d=1.333, \
volume=enable='between(t,8,12)':volume=.25:eval=frame, \
afade=enable='between(t,12,13)':t=in:st=11.6667:d=1.333, \
afade=enable='between(t,15,18)':t=out:st=15:d=3" \
$out
```

Fade filters go to or start from zero, so the trick is to set your fade start time, duration, and enabled range such that the volume at the range start and end time is at the level desired. The default curve is linear, so the calculations should be simple.

Comment: Yes, that works amazingly well. I imagine, even with different curves on the `afade`, an insertion point could be found to make it seem smooth. But I must admit, I was looking forward to seeing how one could do it using only the `volume` filter! If the volume path grew more complex, I was wondering if more control could be had that way.

Comment: Ok, an example. This is what fade out to 25% would be with volume: `volume=enable='between(t,7,8)':volume='1 - 0.75 * (t - 7)':eval=frame`

Comment: Fantastic! I was having trouble chaining `volume` filters before, but figured it out. I'm going to write out your solution above, but using `volume`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to the (great) answer by @Mulvya, here is a method using the `volume` filter that produces the same output:

```
infile="infile.caf"
outfile="outfile.mp3"

ffmpeg -i $ina -af \
"volume=enable='between(t,0,3)':volume='t / 3.0':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,3,7)':volume='1':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,7,8)':volume='1 - 0.75 * (t - 7)':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,8,12)':volume='0.25':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,12,13)':volume='.25 + 0.75 * (t - 12)':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,13,15)':volume='1':eval=frame, \
volume=enable='between(t,15,18)':volume='1 - (t - 15) / 3.0':eval=frame" \
$out
```